# Regex to split double company names?

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of company names that sometimes contain two company names, separated by `/`.

I would like to split them apart and only take the second company if two.

A problem I run into is that the company names often contain things like `A/S` at their end as well.

*Updated data:*

```
Food Done Inc.
Marina-Dock Salt Fishing Ltd
Frederikson Bay K/S
Food Bridge S/A/Natural Samslo
Anabelle Nautico A/S/Frederikson Bay K/S
Anabelle Nautico A/S/Food Done Inc.
Sono Sara And Co/33/36 Partnership
C-4 Summa A/C Development Sys/Finfruit Inc
A/S NOVO Fishing
A/S NOVO Fishing/Kurlag Tours
D & D 23/21 LLC/A-OK Boats
...
```

Right now, I only check for parts if a first simple string test verified that `/` is part of the name.

Then I run a regex and captured the offset of the `/` I thought is the best place to split, but it fails for those single entries that have a `/`.

Instead of splitting at a certain position, I thought I can much easier solve this with a named match, so that I can just pick the name match after run.

This is sort of stub I though can do it, but I have problems to find the right regex:

```
$pattern = '((?P<named>##company-1##)|(##company-1##/(?P<named>##company-2##))';
$result = preg_match($pattern, $name, $matches);
if (!$result) {
   // pattern not useful.
} else {
   $company = $match['named'];
   echo $company, "\n";
}
```

I think the pattern for the companies can/shoud always be the same but I always stumble over the problem of multiple `/`'s.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this is doable or not, but i recommend switching to a different separator. Something like a semicolon, or a character that's highly unlikely to be used. Or, in the company names you can escape the true forward slashes with a back slash or something, and account for that in your regular expression.

Comment: The sadly part is that I have no influence of the thousand input strings. I would have not stored in that way ;), I only need to deal with it ;)

Comment: +1 for agmcleod: I doubt that it's going to be possible to produce a 100% reliable regex for this while you're using a separator that also appears in the text you want to separate. You can get reasonably close, perhaps, but you'll always have a nagging doubt that something unwanted could get through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
$arr = array(
    'Food Done Inc.',
    'Marina-Dock Salt Fishing Ltd',
    'Frederikson Bay K/S',
    'Food Bridge S/A/Natural Samslo',
    'Anabelle Nautico A/S/Frederikson Bay K/S',
    'Anabelle Nautico A/S/Food Done Inc.',
    'Sono Sara And Co/33/36 Partnership',
    'C-4 Summa A/C Development Sys/Finfruit Inc',
    'A/S NOVO Fishing/Kurlag Tours',
    'A/S NOVO Fishing',
    'D & D 23/21 LLC/A-OK Boats'
);


foreach ($arr as $name) {
    preg_match('~(?P<name>(?:./. )?[^/]+(?: ./.)?)$~', $name, $match);
    echo $name ,"\t=> ", $match['name'], "\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
Food Done Inc.  => Food Done Inc.
Marina-Dock Salt Fishing Ltd    => Marina-Dock Salt Fishing Ltd
Frederikson Bay K/S     => Frederikson Bay K/S
Food Bridge S/A/Natural Samslo  => Natural Samslo
Anabelle Nautico A/S/Frederikson Bay K/S        => Frederikson Bay K/S
Anabelle Nautico A/S/Food Done Inc.     => Food Done Inc.
Sono Sara And Co/33/36 Partnership      => 36 Partnership
C-4 Summa A/C Development Sys/Finfruit Inc      => Finfruit Inc
A/S NOVO Fishing/Kurlag Tours   => Kurlag Tours
A/S NOVO Fishing        => A/S NOVO Fishing
D & D 23/21 LLC/A-OK Boats      => A-OK Boats
```

Comment: Thanks. Quite. I want it that if `K/S` is part of the company name it should be returned. And I need the second name. However I've learned that a named group can only taken once. Otherwise I get a regex warning.

Comment: Thanks M42, and please don't call me a bitch, but while running your well working pattern, ya know, the real problematic entries turned up. I've added it to the data in the question but I think this is going to the limit of regex.

Comment: @hakre: What do you want as result for the last entries you've given ?

Comment: Always the last company name, e.g. for `D & D 23/21 LLC/A-OK Boats` it's `A-OK Boats` or for `A/S NOVO Fishing` it would be `A/S NOVO Fishing` (I should put that into the data) or for `C-4 Summa A/C Development Sys/Finfruit Inc` it would be `Finfruit Inc`. But I think the point is, this is not solveable with regex. Would need a change of strategy.

Comment: It's a great strategy to work from the end. I think that is the solution, I have running something similar against this massive amount of data and it looks very, very good! Thanks a lot!  ---- `~(?P<name>(?:(?:[AP]/[LS] )|(?:\d{2}/\d{2}))?[^/]+(?: ./.)?)$~`

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
<?php

$companies = array(
        'Food Done Inc.',
        'Marina-Dock Salt Fishing Ltd',
        'Frederikson Bay K/S',
        'Food Bridge S/A/Natural Samslo',
        'Anabelle Nautico A/S/Frederikson Bay K/S',
        'Anabelle Nautico A/S/Food Done Inc.'
    );
$pattern = '~^([^/]+(?:/[a-z])?)/(.{2,})$~i';
foreach ($companies as $company) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $company, $matches)) {
        echo $matches[1] . ' - ' . $matches[2] . "\n";
    } else {
        echo $company . "\n";
    }
}
```

Works with the provided companies.

Comment: Looks good and keeps the company type in the result. But I fear I have some `/` as well sometimes in the first company. However will check that, I think it's pretty specific and I can filter that.

Comment: Can it be written, that I can check with `$result` from `preg_match` (if true) that it is valid? Otherwise if the pattern does not match, it assumes that it's always one company. That's too verbose.